# Common asserts in any automation project

Tags: validation, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, verification, assertion

Can anyone briefly explain what are the common asserts to consider in any automation project please. Whether it might be an in-house or public web application. For example presently i am using selenium (java) to automate an eCommerce web application. As this is my first website to automate, i am running out of ideas where i can verify things expect few which i know mentioned below:

1.Verify each page Title

2.Verify a button, text, link, image, custom text etc

Apart from these is there any thing else i can verify? please feel free to correct my question and if you have worked on various automation projects which areas did you add asserts to verify or validate something on a webpage.

Comment: Might get a better response on sqa.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @jsheeran: thanks i will give a try there too..

Comment: You can test the styles (css clases) the components have, you can click in the button and expect that some functionality is reflected on the screen (error, or success). You can test redirections, etc. Test automation is like if a human would be interacting with the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically, you do automation to decrease the execution time of regression cycles by automating the `Test Cases` relate to the functionality of the application. so, first develop test cases, using test design techniques like `ECP, BVA` etc.

Each test case must have an Assertion called expected result or functionality (otherwise it won't be called a Test case).

This assertion can be anything like,

1. Whether login successful after giving valid credentials
2. Showing an error message after entering wrong credentials etc.

Selenium helps us to automate web interactions (navigations, clicks, enter texts etc.) and don't perform any assertions for you.

Assertions are available by frameworks like `JUnit, TestNG` (in Java) with `Assertions` class. There is built-in support from programming languages like `assert` keyword in python & Java (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html)

So, whatever you mentioned in your question like common assertions (Verify each page Title etc.), those are just web interactions. they don't decide whether a Test is `PASS or FAIL`. **It is you who define the criteria whether a Test is PASS/FAIL.**

---

For example, there is a **test case** related to **successful login**.

here, you automate web interactions like navigate to login page, enter credentials, click Submit button.

Then to validate whether you successfully logged in or not, you look for a web element in the Home Page of the user logged in (like, `welcome user`) in normal scenario. In Automation, you try to find the text `welcome user` using webelement. Then you use Assertions provided by frameworks, to assert whether the expected message is present in the webpage like

```
Assertions.assertEqual(expected_message, actual_message); // just an example.
```

If expected_message and actual_message is same, then the method don't throw any exception, which results in marking the testcase as PASS by the framework

If expected_message and actual_message is NOT same, then AssertionError is raised by the method assertEqual, which results in marking the test case as FAIL by the framework.

Comment: Brilliant!! very well explained, this definitely helps me to think further.Thanks Naveen..